# Wide streams and char

Tags: c++, widechar

I see that it is allowed to write a `char` to a `std::wostream` (for example, `std::wcout<<"looooool";`).

How are the `char` changed to `wchar` (if that's what happens)?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbrtowc

Comment: I don't see any `std::string`s.

Comment: so is it wise or not to add char to a wide stream? or i am better with adding wchar instead of converting every time? or it dont matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send a `char` or a c-string (`char *`) to a wide stream, the ìndividual octets (bytes) are converted to wchar with [`widen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/widen). There is no automatic conversion from a `std::string`.

You cannot send multibyte UTF-8 characters into a wide stream this way, because the bytes are converted one at a time. In the default locale, there is no conversion from a non-ascii character to a wide character, so the conversion will fail, putting the wide stream into error state.

Whether you take advantage of this conversion or not is up to you; the standard allows it, and for character and string literals, at least, it seems harmless to me. But do be aware that string objects you send to a wide stream must be `std::wstring`, not `std::string`.